# How to fill my data.table without using two for-loops?

Tags: r, data.table

I wasn't able to find an answer anywhere, I probably didn't get the right search terms or wasn't able to transfer the problems to mine.

So I hope that someone here is able to help me.

I have a data.table dt1 in the following form (I tried to keep it short, but needed to include all possibilities):

```
ID  session
101  1
101  1
101  2
101  4
102  2
102  4
102  5
103  1
103  4
201  1
201  4
201  5
202  1
202  2
203  1
204  5
```

Code to reproduce this:

```
dt1 <- data.table(ID=c(101, 101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 103, 103, 201, 201, 201, 202, 202, 203, 204), session=c(1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 5, 1, 4, 1, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 5))
```

What I want in a first step is a data.table in the form, where there is a 1 for each session when there is an entry in the input data.frame and a 0 where not.

```
ID  1   2   3   4   5
101 1   1   0   1   0
102 0   1   0   1   1
103 1   0   0   1   0
201 1   0   0   1   1
202 1   1   0   0   0
203 1   0   0   0   0
204 0   0   0   0   1
```

Right now, I am generating two lists,

```
IDs <- sort(unique(dt1$ID))
sessions <- unique(dt1$session)
```

an empty data.table `dt2` with `ncol=length(sessions)` and `nrow=length(IDs)`, with the sessions as column names

```
dt2 <- data.table(matrix(ncol=length(sessions), nrow=length(IDs)))
colnames(dt2) <- as.character(unique(dt1$session))
```

and  a list with sessions per ID.

```
sesID <- split(dt1$session, dt1$ID)
```

Then I run through the lists with two for loops.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(dt2)) {
 for (j in 1:length(dt2)) {
  if (sessions[j] %in% sesID[i]) {
    set(dt2, i, j, 1)s
  }
  else {
    set(dt2, i, j, 0)
  } } }
```

As a second step, I want to change all the 0s into 1s, if the the sessions lies between sessions with 1s.

```
ID  1   2   3   4   5
101 1   1   1   1   0
102 0   1   1   1   1
103 1   1   1   1   0
201 1   0   0   1   1
202 1   1   0   0   0
203 1   0   0   0   0
204 0   0   0   0   1
```

I am doing this with another two for loops.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(dt2)) {
 trues <- which(dt2[i,]==1)
 headTrues <- head(trues, 1)
 tailTrues <- tail(trues, 1)
 for (j in 1:length(dt2)){
  if (j > headTrues & j < tailTrues & headTrues <= tailTrues){
    set(dt2, i, j, 1)
} } }
```

As this generates me a data.table dt3 with TRUEs and FALSEs I replace them afterwards.

```
(to.replace <- names(which(sapply(dt3, is.logical)))) 
for (var in to.replace) dt3[, var:= as.numeric(get(var)), with=FALSE]
```

To keep the IDs as a column, I add them afterwards.

```
dt3$ID <- IDs
```

This would be okay, if I wouldn't have around 12000 unique IDs and needed to do a couple of thousands runs. I am pretty sure that there are much better ways to do this in R. I just don't now them yet.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: See `help("dcast.data.table")` for the first step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using:

```
# create a reference data.table which includes also 'session 3'
ref <- CJ(ID = dt1$ID, session = min(dt1$session):max(dt1$session), unique = TRUE)
# join 'ref' with 'dt1' and create a new variable that has NA's
# for values that don't exist in 'dt1$session'
ref[dt1, on = c('ID','session'), ses2 := i.session]

# summarise to create a dummy and reshape to wide format with the 'dcast'-function
dcast(ref[, sum(!is.na(ses2)), .(ID,session)], 
      ID ~ session, value.var = 'V1')
```

you get:

```
    ID 1 2 3 4 5
1: 101 1 1 0 1 0
2: 102 0 1 0 1 1
3: 103 1 0 0 1 0
4: 201 1 0 0 1 1
5: 202 1 1 0 0 0
6: 203 1 0 0 0 0
7: 204 0 0 0 0 1
```

An alternative (as proposed by @Frank in the comments):

```
dt1[, session := factor(session, levels=1:5)]
dcast(dt1, ID ~ session, fun = function(x) sign(length(x)), drop = FALSE)
```

which will give you the same result.

---

If you want to fill the zero's between 1's, you could use the `shift`-function to check whether the preceding and the next value are equal to `1`:

```
dcast(ref[, sum(!is.na(ses2)), .(ID,session)
          ][shift(V1,1,0,'lag')==1 & shift(V1,1,0,'lead')==1, V1 := 1L, ID],
      ID ~ session, value.var = 'V1')
```

you will then get:

```
    ID 1 2 3 4 5
1: 101 1 1 1 1 0
2: 102 0 1 1 1 1
3: 103 1 0 0 1 1
4: 201 1 0 0 1 1
5: 202 1 1 0 0 0
6: 203 1 0 0 0 0
7: 204 0 0 0 0 1
```

---

In response to your comment, to replace all zero's between 1's you can use a combination of the `rle` and `inverse.rle` functions:

```
dt2 <- unique(dt1)[, val := 1
                   ][CJ(ID = ID, session = min(session):max(session), unique = TRUE), on = c('ID','session')
                     ][is.na(val), val := 0
                       ][, val := {rl <- rle(val);
                                   rl$values[rl$values==0 & shift(rl$values,fill=0)==1 & shift(rl$values,fill=0,type='lead')==1] <- 1;
                                   inverse.rle(rl)},
                         ID]

dcast(dt2, ID ~ session, value.var = 'val')
```

This gives:

```
    ID 1 2 3 4 5
1: 101 1 1 1 1 0
2: 102 0 1 1 1 1
3: 103 1 1 1 1 0
4: 201 1 1 1 1 1
5: 202 1 1 0 0 0
6: 203 1 0 0 0 0
7: 204 0 0 0 0 1
```

Alternately (@Frank's idea):

```
ref[, v := 0L]
ref[dt1[, .(first(session), last(session)), by=ID], on=.(ID, session >= V1, session <= V2), 
  v := 1L ]
dcast(ref, ID ~ session)
```

---

When all different session numbers are present in the dataset, you also use a nested `dcast`/`melt`-approach as an alternative to one with a cross-join (with regard to speed and memory efficiency, the previous approach with a cross-join (`CJ`) is preferrable).

New example dataset:

```
DT <- data.table(ID=c(101, 101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 103, 103, 201, 201, 201, 202, 202, 203, 204), 
                 session=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 5, 1, 4, 1, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 5))
```

The code:

```
dcast(melt(dcast(DT[, val := 1], 
                 ID ~ session,
                 value.var = 'val',
                 fill = 0), 
           id = 'ID')[, value := {rl <- rle(value);
           rl[[2]][rl[[2]]==0 & shift(rl[[2]],1,0)==1 & shift(rl[[2]],1,0,'lead')==1] <- 1;
           inverse.rle(rl)},
           ID],
      ID ~ variable, value.var = 'value')
```

This gives:

```
    ID 1 2 3 4 5
1: 101 1 1 1 1 0
2: 102 0 1 1 1 1
3: 103 1 1 1 1 0
4: 201 1 1 1 1 1
5: 202 1 1 0 0 0
6: 203 1 0 0 0 0
7: 204 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: Thank you. There is an ID for every session in the data, I just forgot to include this in the example data. I want to fill the zeros if there are one or more zeros between two 1s.

Comment: @Frank thx, true & added :-) -- for the replacement of the zeros, I think the `CJ`-approach icw `rle` is still needed

Comment: This works great and fast! Thank you very much. Although I have to admit that I have to go through the documentation to understand what you did there.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `reshape`.

First create a column `value` equal to 1:

```
dt1[, value :=  1]
```

And now `reshape` it to `wide` format:

```
dt1.1 <- reshape(dt1, direction = "wide", idvar = "ID", timevar = "session")
```

You will get this:

```
    ID value.1 value.2 value.4 value.5
1: 101       1       1       1      NA
2: 102      NA       1       1       1
3: 103       1      NA       1      NA
4: 201       1      NA       1       1
5: 202       1       1      NA      NA
6: 203       1      NA      NA      NA
7: 204      NA      NA      NA       1
```

Replace `NA` with `0`:

```
dt1.1[is.na(dt1.1)] <- 0

    ID value.1 value.2 value.4 value.5
1: 101       1       1       1       0
2: 102       0       1       1       1
3: 103       1       0       1       0
4: 201       1       0       1       1
5: 202       1       1       0       0
6: 203       1       0       0       0
7: 204       0       0       0       1
```

**Alternatively with `dcast`:**

```
dcast(ID ~ session, data = dt1, fun.aggregate = function(x) as.numeric(length(x) > 0))

   ID 1 2 4 5
1 101 1 1 1 0
2 102 0 1 1 1
3 103 1 0 1 0
4 201 1 0 1 1
5 202 1 1 0 0
6 203 1 0 0 0
7 204 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: Not same as expected output, column `3` is missing.

Comment: That is because in your test data you don't have any 3... And therefore the mothod of @Jav don't generate a column for 3 if it does not find it in the data itself.

Comment: Thank you, both ways work much faster than my approach. There is indeed an ID for every session in the large dataset. I overlooked that in the test data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the first step in this way... Is that what you are looking for?

```
library(dplyr)
df_dt1 %>% group_by (ID) %>% summarize (S1 = as.integer(sum(session == 1)>0), 
                                    S2 = as.integer(sum(session ==2)>0), 
                                    S3 = as.integer(sum(session ==3)>0),
                                    S4 = as.integer(sum(session ==4)>0),
                                    S5 = as.integer(sum(session ==5)>0))
```

you get

```
     ID    S1    S2    S3    S4    S5
  <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1   101     1     1     0     1     0
2   102     0     1     0     1     1
3   103     1     0     0     1     0
4   201     1     0     0     1     1
5   202     1     1     0     0     0
6   203     1     0     0     0     0
7   204     0     0     0     0     1
```

Comment: Could you please explain for me why for example S1 = as.integer(sum(session == 1)>0) returns only 1 or 0? I see it is because you add >0, but cant understand what makes it return 1 or 0.

Comment: @MLEN Logical TRUE/FALSE becomes 1/0 when converted to integer.